# how to create Gtk widgets inside a class in vala?

Tags: class, gtk, window, vala

I have a class that inherits button and it looks like this:

```
public class MyButton : Button {
     Gtk.Image image; // This doesn't work
}
```

I need to initiate a GTK Widget that belongs to the class "MyButton". However, I can't really do it. Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code (perhaps a warning about hiding the ''image'' property). In what way is it not working? Any error messages at compile time or at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what exactly you're trying to do... If you're trying to set the image property of the GtkButton (see http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkButton.html#GtkButton--image), something like this should work:

```
public class MyButton : Gtk.Button {
  public MyButton (Gtk.Image image) {
    GLib.Object ();
    this.image = image;
  }
}
```

Comment: Recently Gtk finalized a lot of these classes like button, spinbutton etc, so it is no longer possible to inherit directly from these classes. Instead you need to inherit from layouts, like widget, box, grid etc.